# Specialize C++ template function that uses generic iterators for pointer value type?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iterator, function-templates

I have a C++ template function that accepts generic iterators as arguments, as below:

(it processes all elements from `first` up to but excluding `last`)

```
void update(const std::uint8_t *const data, const size_t len)
{
    /* ... */
}

template<typename iterator_type>
void update(const iterator_type &first, const iterator_type &last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<iterator_type>::value_type value_type;
    for (iterator_type iter = first; iter != last; ++iter)
    {
        update(reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(std::addressof(*iter)), sizeof(value_type));
    }
}
```

This is working, so far. My only problem is: If the *value_type* of the iterator happens to be a pointer type, then this function processes the pointer value (memory address) rather than the actual value (object) that the pointer is pointing to. So, I'd like to handle pointer types specially. Is there a good way in C++ to provide a specialization of this template function for iterators whose *value_type* is a pointer type?

I tried to solve this with a single function and an `if(is_pointer)... else...` construct, like this:

```
void update(const iterator_type &first, const iterator_type &last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<iterator_type>::value_type value_type;
    if(std::is_pointer<value_type>::value)
    {
        for (iterator_type iter = first; iter != last; ++iter)
        {
            update(reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(*iter), sizeof(std::pointer_traits<value_type>::element_type));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (iterator_type iter = first; iter != last; ++iter)
        {
            update(reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t*>(std::addressof(*iter)), sizeof(value_type));
        }
    }
}
```

...but, unfortunately, this doesn't compile for non-pointer types:

```
error C2039: 'element_type': is not a member of 'std::pointer_traits<value_type>'
```

Comment: Does your compiler support C++17? If so simply change your if to an if constexpr. See your C++ book, updated for C++17, for more details.

Comment: For compatibility, the code should compile with VS2010 and later (as well as MinGW, GCC and Clang), so I'd much prefer to **not** use C++17-only features.

Comment: What if someone intends to use the function to act on the pointers? I think the clearer solution in line with how the std library works for something like this would be for the caller to use some iterator adaptor that does the dereferencing or for `update` to take an optional transforming lambda.

Comment: In my context, if the caller has a container (std::vector, std::list, etc.) of pointers, it wouldn't make much sense to process the pointers (which are more or less "random" memory addresses) as data; but it's save to assume the caller actually wants to process the data that these pointers are pointing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to write a template functor to update a single item, and specialize that. Then, have your update template function invoke the class. Something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct Update {
    void operator () (const T &v) {
        //...
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Update<T *> {
    void operator () (const T *v) {
        //...
    }
};


template <typename T>
void update (const T &v) {
    Update<T>()(v);
}
```

Then inside the loop, you call it like:

```
update(*iter);
```

---

You could parameterize the update functor into the update function template, to provide flexibility to the caller if they want to do something different from the default update handling.

```
template <typename T, typename U = Update<T>>
void update (const T &v, U u = U{}) {
    u(v);
}
```

Then, the previous invocation still works, but you could also pass in a different callable (like a lambda).

```
update(*iter, [](int *){ /* ... */ });
```

Comment: This basic idea works nicely for me. However, *specializing* the templated `update()` function didn't work, so I just created two separate overloads - one for pointers, one for refs.

Comment: @MuldeR: Sorry about that, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This question already has a good answer, but I'll throw in here that type traits and tag dispatch make overloading between iterators with pointer and non-pointer value types easy:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void update_tag_dispatch(T first, T last, std::true_type) {
    std::cout << "iterator value is a pointer!\n";
}

template <typename T>
void update_tag_dispatch(T first, T last, std::false_type) {
    std::cout << "iterator value is not a pointer\n";
}

template <typename T>
void update_tag_dispatch(T first, T last) {
    update_tag_dispatch(first, last, std::is_pointer<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*first)>>{});
}
```

You can also use its cousin, `std::enable_if_t`:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>>::value>* = nullptr>
void update_enable_t(T first, T last) {
    std::cout << "iterator value is a pointer!\n";
}
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>>::value>* = nullptr>
void update_enable_t(T first, T last) {
    std::cout << "iterator value is a pointer!\n";
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/t7YbcF